# Посоветуйте способ хранения данных о пользователях

Tags: mysql

Это однозначно спорный вопрос, и определиться со способом решения этой задачи достаточно трудно. С одной стороны у нас реляционная модель базы данных, которая описана во всех учебниках как единственно правильная, и с другой стороны появилась информация что несколько высоко нагруженных проектов отказались от этого подхода в пользу ключ-значение.

Собственно вопрос. Речь идет о развернутой системе для работы с пользователями, нет я не пишу свою соцеальную сеть :). Но хочется достичь высокого уровня универсальности в этом плане, поскольку именно пользователи есть тем ради чего мы все работаем. Если можно немного подробнее как лучше разделять данные. Почта, счет с балансом пользователя, его адрес, рейтинги и прочая ерунда вроде вкусов, размеров его друзей, личных сообщения и.т.д
 Тоисть интересует реально лучшая модель заслужившая признание специалистами мира. Желательно на примере MySQL.

ps. Хороший у вас проект! Ссылку увидел когда читал почту на яндексе. Респект вам!

Comment: Я бы дополнил вопрос:   

Представьте, что система `очень` большая и обрабатывает ее один сервер; также представьте, что не имеет смысла кэшировать данные, (т.к. данных очень много и популярность записей очень разнообразна) и в базу надо очень быстро как вносить данные, так и извлекать их; также данные очень разнообразны (от текстовых полей до звуковых записей); учтите размер записываемых/извлекаемых данных, который также разнообразен (допустим, от 8Kb до 8Gb)...    

Также, что бы вы сказали про разные виды таблиц и организации данных. Какие себя в чем оправдали.

Comment: @Антон Мухин: Каждой задаче — свое оптимальное решение. Но конкретной задаче, а не «надо сделать большую молотилку данных для высоких нагрузок» (это не задача, это присказка).

(Шутя) А на такой абстрактной задаче можно сказать только что нужен MongoDB. Because [MongoDB is web scale](http://www.xtranormal.com/watch/6995033/mongo-db-is-web-scale).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы вам рекомендовал не употреблять слова "высоко нагруженных проектов" и "ключ-значение"  в одном предложении.

+ У вас УЖЕ начинается синдром "Преждевременной оптимизации"

в любом случае никто адекватного ответа вам дать не в состоянии ибо никто не знает точно что именно вам нужно. Попытайтесь сделать первую версию структуры БД. Например [тут](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)
И представить на "суд" с вопросом что бы вы изменили. И то это не даст 100% гарантии что это будет "правильно" ибо без реальных тестов нету никакой уверенности что всё будет именно так как предполагалось.

В общим дерзайте.

Comment: >+ У вас УЖЕ начинается синдром "Преждевременной оптимизации"

Преждевременной оптимизации не существует. Если проект наберет обороты - то потом может быть практически нереально проводить рефакторинг кода и базы. Поэтому нужно продумывать варианты сразу.

Comment: На счет синдрома, это вполне возможно. Есть некий страх ошибиться. Тем более это для себя делается, а опыта работы с проектом который имеет огромный онлайн нет. Поэтому и интересует вопрос, как организована структура у проектов которые выдерживают реальные потоки запросов. Интересует может сможете пальцем ткнуть, в любой из CMS проектов например на предмет что вот эта структура мне реально нравится потому что так и так.

Comment: Можете расписать какие будут функции у проекта? хотя бы примерно. Тогда будет возможность показать вам пример структуры базы для вашего случая

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про [нормальные формы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) БД. Тогда и поймете как лучше организовать структуру БД, чтоб данные не дублировались

Comment: В данный момент вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Прочитал рекомендованную вами статью, ну я, как бы, в курсе всего этого. Вот об этом и речь. Есть нормализация данных и денормализация с целью снять нагрузку. Где-то должна быть середина что ли...

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело вот в чем. В MySQL есть такая штука как кэширование результатов. Работает оно следующим образом, к примеру вы выполняете запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = 8
```

То в случае если в следующий раз будете делать этот же запрос, то данные вернутся значительно быстрее, так как результат берется из кэша. Но это действует только в том случае если с момента последней выборки в таблицу не вносились изменения.

Поэтому я предпочитаю делать так:

Статичные данные которые меняются редко - выносятся в отдельную таблицу, а данные которые дергаются часто идут в другую таблицу.

Очень много зависит от того какая у вас итоговая цель. В том примере что вы написали я бы делал так:

Таблица user: id, name, mail, adress и пр (данные которые пользователь вводит при регистрации и которые меняются в пятилетку)

А остальные данные пишутся в разные таблицы связанные только по ключу.

По тому что я вынес в процессе работы я понял что не надо гнаться за желанием уместить все в одной таблице, это тяжело и в плане суппорта и в плане скорости работы.

Кроме этого надо не забывать правильно проставлять индексы к таблицам.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [LDAP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP). Но ставить бэкендом для LDAP реляционку, в том числе MySQL — плохая идея.

Comment: Ваша идея понятна, но она из поля зрения настройки сервера к бою. А меня интересует что я как программист могу сделать для того чтобы улутшить положение системы.